# angular test and getting errors in e2e

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass an end to end test with angular for the first version of my app. I am getting the following error which i have no idea how to solve it.In fact the app loads the favicon, but there is and error in e2e test.

Including the browser pause, workspace-project App should display texfggt

> Expected [ Entry({ level: SEVERE, message:
>   'http://localhost:4200/favicon.ico - Failed to load resource: the
>   server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)', timestamp:
>   1560874255990, type: '' }) ] not to contain

Answer (score 0):

Do a global search in your IDE for `favicon`. There's a chance it's been called incorrectly somewhere. angular.json, index.html, and sometimes other files will reference it. If you've changed the file type, renamed it, or moved it to an assets folder, you'll run into this problem.

Icons also tend to get cached. Clear your cache (F12 to open dev tools, right click refresh button > Empty Cache) and see if it still shows up in your browser when you serve the app.

Comment: I have actually resturned back the "favicon.ico" to most of the folders. The app can run and render the icon without any issue, the problem is only end to end test